# Как остановить группу объектов при столкновении с персонажем?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Начинаю изучать Unity + C#. Делаю игру похожую на Flappy Bird и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Хочу после смерти персонажа остановить мир полностью и отключить коллайдер на препятствиях, все мои попытки не увенчались успехом. При накладывании скрипта на один объект, все работает как надо, НО останавливается собственно только он.
сейчас код выглядит подобным образом (попытался сделать с помощью имитации жив/мертв по отношению к преграде) -

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class Map : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _isAlive = true;
    private BoxCollider2D BoxC;
    public float speed;
    void Update()
    {
        if (_isAlive == true)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.left * (speed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        if (_isAlive == false) 
        {
            GameObject[] gameObjects;
            gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
            {
                BoxC.enabled = false;
                transform.Translate(Vector2.left * (0 * Time.deltaTime));
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            _isAlive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Так-же прилагаю скриншот (может быть поможет с решением проблемы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]